# How can i pre select configurbale option of product in product page magento2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

How can I preselect the configurable option of a configurable product with its price in the product page

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Help customers to make an add to cart without selecting options

https://github.com/magepow/magento-2-configurable-preselect

Comment: It is good thank you But is any possible way to change the value from the configurable.js file? i think it can be done with that js

Answer (score 0):

you can try also this reference :

https://magecomp.com/blog/auto-select-first-child-product-of-configurable-product-magento-2/